# How do I properly construct and call a class method from a different class method in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I am writing a WordPress plugin, currently working on the admin side. I'm using classes for this project. The trouble I've run into probably stems from my inexperience.

I have two classes, one for the admin page, and the other to handle custom database table creation, deletion, queries, etc.

I thought that in order to do several database operations, it would make sense to create the tables object (*$db*) when the *tools_page* method is invoked. That is reflected in the code below. However, the call *$db->create_update_tables()* complains that *$db* is not found.

If I move the creation of *$db* to the *db_tables* method, the code runs.

I thought that since the methods involved were public, the $db object should be available to the other methods inside the admin page. I was under the impression from my research the preferred way was to declare a single global *$wpdb* for use with all the database calls while the plugin is running. If I'm not correct, what is the right way to do this?

The admin class:

```
class Home_Search_Admin {

    public function __construct( $plugin_name, $version, $db_version ) {

        $this->plugin_name = $plugin_name;
        $this->version = $version;
        $this->db_version = $db_version;

    }

    public function db_tables() {

        echo "Inside db_tables";
        $db->create_update_tables();
        wp_die();
    }

    public function tools_page() {

        include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'partials/home-search-admin-display.php' );
        $db = new Home_Search_Tables();
        $this->db_tables();
    }
}
```

The class for the tables:

```
class Home_Search_Tables {

    private $wpdb;

    public function __construct() {

        global $wpdb;
        $this->wpdb = $wpdb;
        print_r("Constructed!");

    }

    public function create_update_tables() {

        print_r( 'I am in the method!' );

    }
}
```

Comment: What warning/error do you get for this? (in error+log). As we don't see the whole code of declaration,using part, it would be good to know output logs

Comment: Show code. All that explaining isn't too helpful when you dont show the actual implementation

Comment: @Elvin85 The error (PHP) is that the $db object is not defined. I've tried to explain it better above. Thanks for your help. Sorry I was slow in getting back to you guys. I was off site all day.

Comment: @TurtleTread You are absolutely right. I should have held off on posting the until tonight when I had more time to write a better question. Thank you for taking the time to look at it.

Comment: Yea your $db variable isn't accessible from another method. You need to assign it to class properties or pass it to the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the only method that needs the table class is your `db_tables()`, you can do as what you said. Move the creation of `$db` to the `db_tables` method.

But If you need the creation to be accessible to all methods, you need to declare the variable like your `$wpbd` under `Home_Search_Tables` class so you can pass it from methods.

```
class Home_Search_Admin {

private $db; // Declare $db
```

On your methods, use `$this->db`

```
public function db_tables() {

    echo "Inside db_tables";
    $this->db->create_update_tables(); // $this->db
```

Same here

```
public function tools_page() {

    include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'partials/home-search-admin-display.php' );
    $this->db = new Home_Search_Tables(); // $this->db
    // Or you can move this creation to construct method if necessary
```

Comment: Combining this with the comment above by @TurtleTread caused me to see the simple error of my thinking: forgetting that I needed to declare $db!